# softtabstop not working

Tags: softtabstop

I have a problem with my softtabstop option.

For some reason when I put this line in my .vimrc `set softtabstop=4` it does nothing. However if I do it as a command `:set softtabstop=4` it does work properly.

Any idea why it's not working as it should?

Comment: How are you judging that `:h sts` is not doing anything? Did you check with `:set sts?` Or did you try it out on some test cases? And what do you exactly want to do with softtabstop? Your exact requirements.

Comment: I have this line in my .vimrc 'set softtabstop=4' but when I check :set sts, I get 'softtabstop=0'. So technically It's working as it should but not as I'd like to.

Comment: Well, then most definitely some settings in your vimrc is setting your softtabstop after you're setting it. Comment out the plugins, and then other lines to figure out which part is causing this.

Comment: Thanks, it was the paste mode. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @klaus pointed out in the comments, it was some other setting that was causing the problem (`set paste` in my case)